# Verify the limit

Tags: limits

I have the following limit: $\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{x^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}$ and i have to verify using the definition. I tried solving it: $\lvert \frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{2}\rvert\lt\alpha\rightarrow -\alpha\lt\frac{x}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{2}\lt\alpha$ but I am not able to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You must mean  $$\lim \limits_{x \to 1} \dfrac{x\color{red}{-1}}{x^2-1}=\dfrac12 $$

Comment: Sorry I did not write it correctly.

Comment: He's pointing out why you can't solve it.  You're trying to solve the wrong inequality.  You need the numerator to be $x-1$, not $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.  Then we want $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-1|<\delta$, then 
$$ 
\left| \frac{x}{x^2 +1} - \frac{1}{2} \right|
= \left| \frac{(x-1)^2}{2(x^2 +1)} \right|
= \frac{(x-1)^2}{2(x^2 +1)}
< \epsilon
$$
Note that for $x>0$, which is what we are interested in since we are looking at $x$ near $1$, we have that $(x^2 +1) > 1$ so
$$ 
\frac{(x-1)^2}{2(x^2 +1)}
< \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}
< \epsilon
$$
which is true if and only if
$$ (x-1)^2 < 2\epsilon$$
$$ \iff \sqrt{(x-1)^2} = |x-1| < |\sqrt{2\epsilon}| $$
So let $\delta = |\sqrt{2\epsilon}|$

Comment: We don't need the absolute value for $ |\sqrt{2\epsilon}|$.

Answer (score 0):

Good rules of thumb, you can often drop the denominator if it is guaranteed to be more than one. It's usually safe to only worry about values of the function within 1 of your  value being approached. Given that, the square of the deviation is less than the deviation itself, so if the deviation is held below some value, so is its square.

We seek a $\delta$ such that $|x-1|<\delta$ implies the following:

$\left| \frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{2}  \right|=\left|\frac{(x-1)^2}{2(1+x^2)}\right|<\epsilon$

If $|x-1|<\delta<1$  , then $|x-1|^2<\delta^2<\delta$.

So if we require

$$\left|\frac{(x-1)^2}{1+x^2}\right|<\left|\frac{\delta}{1+x^2}\right|<\epsilon$$

The denominator is greater than 1 for all values of $x$.

So $\left|\frac{\delta}{1+x^2} \right|<\delta$.

So we choose a $\delta<\epsilon$ and guarantee $\left|\frac{(x-1)^2}{2(1+x^2)}\right|\le\epsilon$

Comment: Isn't it $\left| \frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{2}  \right|=\left|\frac{(x-1)^2}{2(1+x^2)}\right|<\epsilon$?

Comment: indeed! good catch.